# C# Xdocument Xml get Element

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have a xml file that looks like this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <s:Body>
  <GetAllArticlesResponse xmlns="http://www.borger.dk/2009/WSArticleExport/v1">
     <GetAllArticlesResult xmlns:a="http://www.borger.dk/2009/WSArticleExport/v1/types" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:ArticleDescription>Test 1</a:ArticleDescription>
        <a:ArticleDescription>Test 2</a:ArticleDescription>
      </GetAllArticlesResult>
  </GetAllArticlesResponse>
 </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I'm trying to get all the articles, but can't get it to work.

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(soapResult);
 IEnumerable<XElement> articles = doc.Root.Descendants("a:ArticleDescription");
```

This has work before, but because the element name as a : then it fails..

Any idea how to fix this.

Thanks for all the inputs.

I ended with::

```
                XNamespace a = "http://www.borger.dk/2009/WSArticleExport/v1/types";
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(soapResult);
                IEnumerable<XElement> articles = doc.Root.Descendants(a + "ArticleDescription");

                List<Article> article = articles.Select(m => new Article()
                {
                    ArticleID = m.Element(a + "ArticleID").Value.ToString(),
                    ArticleTitle = m.Element(a + "ArticleTitle").Value.ToString(),
                    ArticleUrl = m.Element(a + "ArticleUrl").Value.ToString(),
                    LastUpdated = m.Element(a + "LastUpdated").Value.ToString(),
                    PublishingDate = m.Element(a + "PublishingDate").Value.ToString()
                }).ToList();
                json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(article);
```

Comment: Your XML example is not well-formed, it's missing an end tag.
Also, in your XML the namespace prefix is "a:", but in your example code you use "s:".

Comment: Sorry, mistyped. Have updated it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alterante way:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(xml);

XNamespace ns1 = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
XNamespace ns2 = "http://www.borger.dk/2009/WSArticleExport/v1";
XNamespace ns3 = "http://www.borger.dk/2009/WSArticleExport/v1/types";

var result = doc.Element(ns1 + "Envelope")
                    .Element(ns1 + "Body")
                        .Element(ns2 + "GetAllArticlesResponse")
                            .Element(ns2 + "GetAllArticlesResult")
                                .Elements(ns3 + "ArticleDescription")
                                    .Select(x => x.Value);
```

Or

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(xml);
var envelope = doc.Root;
var body = (XElement)envelope.FirstNode;
var getAllArticlesResponse = (XElement)body.FirstNode;
var getAllArticlesResult = (XElement)getAllArticlesResponse.FirstNode;
var articleDescriptions = getAllArticlesResult.Nodes().Cast<XElement>();
var result = articleDescriptions.Select(x => x.Value);
```

Comment: You should always prefer to use `Elements()` over `Element()` when chaining, that way if any produces no results, you get an empty collection rather than null.

Comment: @JeffMercado true, I'm more of a build a class and deserialize type of guy, just wanted to show him how to traverse the xml in the most intuitive way

Answer (score 1):

Here is easiest way using Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication137
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            string[] description = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "ArticleDescription").Select(x => (string)x).ToArray();

        }

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The prefix `a:` is a short-for of the namespace name `"http://www.borger.dk/2009/WSArticleExport/v1/types"`, you can see that where the prefix is declared.

You can use namespace-aware `XName`'s when querying:

```
var descriptions = doc.Root.Descendants(
  XName.Get("ArticleDescription", "http://www.borger.dk/2009/WSArticleExport/v1/types"));
```

Of course you could store the namespaces you want in variables, you don't have to type them out every time.

You can also just look at the local names, if you're not worried about collisions.

```
var descriptions = doc.Root.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "ArticleDescription");
```